# roman page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, page, roman-numerals

Roman page numbers don't appear in kaobook; in preface and toc. If it is considered the first page of a chapter, I've added it in the preface using lipsum, but they still don't appear. While page numbers appear in toc. Please advise, what should I do?
Thank you in advance.
[image: Roman page numbers]

Comment: I think in kaobook `\chapter` definition, there is `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

Comment: You could patch the \chapter definition using `etoolbox`. You should provide a MWE.

Comment: it's worked; thank you very much https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/267375/tom